# To get Clients hostname without using DNS look up using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hostname, intranet, reverse-dns

I am searching since 3 weeks not getting any content..
I can get hostname using DNS server.. however it is accurate since our DNS server takes long time to update..

Is there any other way to find hostname..

PLS help..

other details:
Intranet Application..
ASP.net C#
IIS 7

Comment: take a look at [here][1] for what you can and what you can't.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315758/specify-which-dns-servers-to-use-to-resolve-hostnames-in-net

Comment: hey thanks but none of our dns servers get upadated before 7 days :(

Answer (score 0):

you have to change only your local machine DNS address see here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/change-tcp-ip-settings

Comment: I said I dont want to use DNS!!!!!! I have found a way using VB script (ActiveX) however it requires special permissions on a browser..