# Specify Nameserver with System.Net.Dns class

Tags: .net, class, powershell, dns

### What I'm trying to do

Query a DNS record using the `System.Net.Dns` class in Powershell using a specific Nameserver.

### Problem

I can't find the method or property to do this.

#### Example Code

```
[System.Net.Dns]::Resolve("stackoverflow.com")

HostName                                Aliases                                 AddressList
--------                                -------                                 -----------
stackoverflow.com                       {}                                      {198.252.206.140}
```

But this resolves with the nameservers listed in my interface configuration.

How can I specify a nameserver to use instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify which DNS servers to use to resolve hostnames in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315758/specify-which-dns-servers-to-use-to-resolve-hostnames-in-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an external .NET library that supports querying an alternate DNS server. For example, check out JH Software Simple DNS.

http://www.simpledns.com/dns-client-lib.aspx

PowerShell now offers a `Resolve-DnsName` command with a `-Server` parameter.

```
Resolve-DnsName -Server 8.8.4.4 -Name trevorsullivan.net
```

Comment: Unfortunately Resolve-DnsName is not part of PowerShell 6 (or Core).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use third party library, you can use the good old nslookup.exe

```
$client="10.110.10.10"
$ns="10.20.1.10"
(nslookup $client $ns |sls address |select -last 1).toString().split(":")[1].trim()
```